# IBM Cloud billing api does not support year

Tags: ibm-cloud

I was looking at the billing API for IBM Cloud, it only supports months [url](https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/usage-metering).

here is my code:

```
def processResourceInstanceUsage(account_id, billMonth):
    METERING_HOST="https://metering-reporting.ng.bluemix.net"
    USAGE_URL="/v4/accounts/"+account_id+"/resource_instances/usage/"+billMonth+"?_limit=100&_names=true"

    url=METERING_HOST+USAGE_URL
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "{}".format(iam_token),
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    response=requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print ("\n\nResource instance usage for first 100 items")
    return response.json()
```

Is there a way to get billing data out for a year? I tried inputting just 2019 instead of 2019-03 but got an error.

Comment: Fetching the 12 months of questions and adding them...?

Comment: @data_henrik - there is no better way?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [IBM Cloud API docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs). There is a [Usage Metering](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/usage-metering#introduction) and a [Usage Reporting API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/metering-reporting#introduction). The former is for a specific service and is more flexible. The latter, for usage reporting, is per account, org, resource group, etc. All requests have to specify the usage month. Thus, there is no request type to report for a year.

IMHO the reasoning behind is that there are many types of "year" and hence monthly reporting is flexible. As a consequence, you would need to perform the requests for each month and sum it up on your own.